# What are the limitations of the Flying Thunder God technique (Flying Raijin Jutsu)?

Tags: naruto

More specifically, how many objects can a user mark simultaneously?

If it's an infinite number, then why don't they mark all the objects around them?

Also, besides the number count issue, what other limitations are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

As from what we have seen this far, if you remember the fight of Minato and the [A](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/A_%28Fourth_Raikage%29) (War Arc 4th Raikage), [Minato](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Minato) had a lot of kunai with the mark of this Jutsu spread around the area. So we can say there has to be a specific limitation.

Also we know this technique is connected to the chakra of each user, so it means there are also some limitations there as it's one he makes it takes some of the chakra user.

As for the longetivity of this justu as from the wikia about [Flying Thunder God Technique(Flying Raijin Jutsu)](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Flying_Thunder_God_Technique):

> As Minato also noted, the marking formula never disappears from a marked target.